# Piping command output to an Empathy chat window

Tags: empathy, command-line, telepathy

This isn't Ubuntu-specific, but since Empathy is the default IM client on Ubuntu, I thought this would be a good place to ask.

I have a script that pulls current weather info from Google's weather API, and I'd like to pipe the output to an Empathy window. I imagine I'd have to do some telepathy scripting. Any hints or tips?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I'd like to avoid scripting telepathy if at all possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want to paste this automatically or manually? If you just want to do it manually, you can do this:

```
program_that_outputs_weather_info | xclip
```

and then just paste using Ctrl-V.

Comment: Or [`xsel -b`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/xsel.1x.html).

Comment: Not **exactly** what I was looking to do, but it'll work I suppose. I always seem to forget about xclip!